# JSON , php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i try to finish my project

this is my program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Search extends Activity {

   TextView error,br2;
   EditText namjal2;
   String i,returnString2;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        br2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.berita2);
        namjal2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.namjalSearch);




   }

   public void clickHandler(View view){
    Intent a = null;
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.find:

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_jalan", namjal2.getText().toString()));


/*            String valid = "1";*/      

        String response = null;

        try {

           response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/searchInfo.php", postParameters);


           String result = response.toString();  
           //parse json data

              try{
                      returnString2 = "";


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                              JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                              Log.i("log_tag","id_kepadatan: "+json_data.getInt("id_kepadatan")+
                                      ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                      ", nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                                      ", status: "+json_data.getString("status")+
                                      ", tanggal: "+json_data.getString("tanggal")+
                                      ", waktu: "+json_data.getString("waktu")+
                                      ", keterangan: "+json_data.getString("keterangan")
                              );

                              //Get an output to the screen
                              returnString2 += "\n" + json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + " mengalami "+ json_data.getString("status")+ " pada "+ json_data.getString("tanggal")+ " waktu "+ json_data.getString("waktu")+ " karena "+ json_data.getString("keterangan");
                      }
              }


              catch(JSONException e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
              }

              try{


               br2.setText(returnString2);


              }


              catch(Exception e){

               Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          

              }   

         }

               catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     

         }
        break;

   case R.id.back:
        a = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
}
   }


}
```

and this my searchInfo.php

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/jakarta');
    $skrg = time();
    $tgl = date("dmY",$skrg);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("proyek akhir");

$query = "SELECT * FROM kepadatan WHERE nama_jalan = '". $_POST["nama_jalan"]."' AND tanggal ='$tgl'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

and when i deploy to emulator, it shows messagge in DDMS like this :

"error parsing data org.json.jsonexception value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray"

can anyone tell me why this is happening?

i really need this....because this is my final project and i only have 1 day to finish this...please help me

thank you

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun on it. See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use PDO or MySQLi - this article will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, here is a good tutorial.

Comment: [Bobby Tables has a new best friend](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Your data fetched from database is not in UTF-8 encoding, so `json_encode` returns `null` instead of JSON object.

Comment: and what code that should i write to get the JSON object then?
can you can you please tell me what should i do?i will much appreciate it Sir
thanks before

Comment: iterate through `$row` before adding it to `$output` and use `iconv` to convert from your encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you parsing Json data, just ensure (check whether) the single / array of data is not null. If you don't check it will throw Null Pointer Exception.